# Why was this question re-opened?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[Does Islam lead to higher crime rates?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19505/does-islam-lead-to-higher-crime-rates?rq=1)

Why was it re-opened? It seems to have

- no notable claim evidence at all (and any notable knowledge on the subject is 100% contradictory to the claim, what with "cut of thieves' hands" being an extremely well known thing for Islam and Arabic countries).

  and to boot,
- is unclear what's being asked and/or too broad (is it asking about correllation or causation? Muslim immigrants living in poor communities, Muslims living in poor Muslim countries or Muslims living in rich Muslim countries?)

Based on current comments, it seems that it was previously validly closed and then reopened, for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an answer but...

1. you recently edited it.
2. you posted this meta-question.
3. I noticed the edited question because it was listed at the top of recently edited questions, thought it should be closed, inspected the history and found several other people had thought so too (but they voted to close so far apart, their votes were "aged away").
4. I closed the question.
5. Three hours passed.
6. I checked meta, and found this meta-question.

So, for what it is worth, it has already been closed, independent of this meta-question.

Comment: I'm curious as to why it was reopened; but thanks for closing!

Answer (score 0):

The question was unanswerable when it was first closed because it was too broad. It was then edited and improved, so I reopened it.

Reopening a question doesn't mean it is necessarily valid, only that it's viable. It doesn't mean, for example, that the claim is necessarily notable. We normally assume claims are notable unless we have reason to suspect otherwise.

There were some subsequent doubts about notability and the question has since been closed because of that.

Regarding your second issue, I think it's a great suggestion to improve the question, but not enough reason for me to vote to close. I think that the question asks for a causal relation and "violent crime" is clear enough to answer.